# why doesn't argparse custom type function work with nargs?

Tags: python, lambda, argparse

These lines work:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('foo', nargs='+', type=lambda x:x.split('/'))
parser.parse_args(['3/5', '4/6']) # output Namespace(foo=[['3', '5'], ['4', '6']])
```

But the following don't. Why?

The only difference is that this time the type caster uses a list comprehension to convert strings to integers.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('foo', nargs='+', type=lambda x:[[int(a), int(b)] for a,b in x.split('/')])
parser.parse_args(['3/5', '4/6']) # Raise error: argument foo: invalid <lambda> value: '3/5'
```

Comment: `[int(x) for x  in '3/5'.split('/')]` produces `[3,5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you're trying to do here is

```
for a, b in '3/5'.split('/')...
```

which is a ValueError ("not enough values to unpack"). `argparse` hides actual errors and responds with a generic `ArgumentError` if there's anything wrong with your `type` function. You might want to use an actual `def` instead to debug it:

```
def test(x):
    try:
        return [[int(a), int(b)] for a,b in x.split('/')]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('foo', nargs='+', type=test)
parser.parse_args(['3/5', '4/6'])
```

Comment: `ValueError` and `TypeError` are turned into generic messages.  The message from `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` is passed though.